# How to get WooCommerce Product Variation Title

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using this to display a WooCommerce product title:

`<?php print $_product->get_title(); ?>`

But it only displays the title of the parent product. How do I display the title of the variant?

Comment: accept correct answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display the title of the variant use `get_name()` function instead `get_title()`.

```
<?php print $_product->get_name(); ?>
```

Comment: That answer must be accepted as a correct answer! @TinyTiger

Answer (score 3):

Variants have attributes and descriptions instead of titles. Unless a title is added using an additional plugin or a custom field, it is inherited from their parent product by default.

If you want to show the description or sku, you can loop through the variations, and obtain the description for each.

```
if ( ( $variations = $_product->get_children() ) ) {
    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
        echo $variation->get_description();
        echo " (" . $variation->get_sku() . ")";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to display all the attributes used to make variations, you can loop through `$_product->get_variation_attributes()` instead.

If titles are added using third party plugins, it would be best to check for documentation for those plugins, as they may provide helper functions for easily displaying the necessary information.

Comment: I've replaced the deprecated method `$variation->get_variation_description()` with `$variation->get_description()`.